# How can I visualise how many processes this code creates?

Tags: c++, c++11, process, fork, unistd.h

How many processes does this piece of code create?

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
    if(fork() == fork())
    break;
}
```

Comment: As many as your system resources allow for.

Comment: [Fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) has a nice picture.

Comment: Apparently it's not a fork bomb.

Answer (score 0):

The first parent spawns five children.  Each of those spawns four children.  Each of those spawns three children, and so on.

So it's:

```
5 * (1 + 4 * (1 + 3 * (1 + 2 * (1 + 1))))
```

Looks like 325 processes spawned, plus the original one.

Comment: Adding a printf just below the for makes 364 output lines. Suggesting the right answer is 363+1.